# name or symbol for "anti" Kronecker delta?

Tags: notation, index-notation, kronecker-symbol

Is there a name or symbol convention for what I might call the "anti" Kronecker delta (that is, $1 - \delta_{ij}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Inverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). If $P$ is a property, then
$$
[P] = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $P$ is true}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, in your case, $[i \not= j]$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an agreed upon notation for this. However, you could just define $\gamma_{ij}=1-\delta_{ij}$ if you need to.